# Run Android Wear Initial Tutorial again

Tags: wear-os

I have pulled this from a dumpsys of com.google.android.wearable.app

```
Service Resolver Table: Non-Data Actions:
  com.google.android.clockwork.home.action.BIND_HOME:
    adc4ff78 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.watchfaces.HomeBackgroundService filter adc79b80
      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.home.action.BIND_HOME"
  com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_FORCE:
    adc9acc8 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.tutorial.TutorialService filter adc9adf8

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_START"

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_FORCE"

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_NEXT_STAGE"

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_SKIP"

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_NOTIFICATION_DISMISSED"

      Action: "com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_DONE"

  com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_START:

    adc9acc8
```

I've tried to run:

```
am start -a com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_START -n com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.tutorial.TutorialService
```

However, I have not been able to restart the initial tutorial again. Any advice would be helpful

Comment: please add the errormessage you receive

Comment: There is nothing, it just doesn't run the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
am startservice -a com.google.android.clockwork.action.TUTORIAL_FORCE -n com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.tutorial.TutorialService
```